# How to send multipart file from angular 4 using http

Tags: spring, angular, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

I need to send a file using multipar file which my spring controller expects.

```
public void test(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {}
```

I know that I have to use `FormData`, but I did not manage to make it work. Here's my code:

```
this.headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'});
this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });

return this.http.post(environment.SERVER_ENDPOINT + 'parameters/area', formData, options)
  .toPromise()
  .then(this.extractData)
  .catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: Whats the issue? Errors? is formData sent a type File?

Answer (score 0):

Use XMLHttpRequest

```
let fd = new FormData();
fd.append("file", file);
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = environment.SERVER_ENDPOINT + 'parameters/area';
xhr.open('POST', url, true);
xhr.send(fd);
```